# An enum deriving Debug

Tags: rust

The following code compiles (In particular MyError is recognized as having trait debug):

```
use std::str;
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyError<F> where F: str::FromStr {
    Parse(F::Err),
    Space,
}

fn my_parse<F>(s: String) -> Result<F,MyError<F>>
    where F: str::FromStr {
    match s.len() {
        0 => Err(MyError::Space),
        _ => s.parse::<F>().map_err(|err| MyError::Parse(err)),
    }
}

fn my_force_parse<F>(s: String) -> F
    where F: str::FromStr, MyError<F>: fmt::Debug {
    my_parse::<F>(s).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    println!("hi");
    let s = "nope".to_string();
    println!("{}", my_force_parse::<i64>(s));
}
```

But if I replace the where statement for `my_force_parse` with

```
where F: str::FromStr
```

then it does not. SHouldn't the program  gather that MyError implements Debug from the #[derive(Debug)] attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyError` *does not* implement `Debug`... *unconditionally*.  Rather, it implements it so long as all the required generic parameters *also* implement it.  In essence, the `#[derive(Debug)]` attribute expands to something roughly like:

```rust
impl<F> MyError<F> where F: Debug {
    ...
}
```

After all, if `F` doesn't implement `Debug`, `MyError` can't provide an implementation.

Additionally, it appears as though `where F: str::FromStr + fmt::Debug` is not sufficient, either.  Presumably, Rust either isn't smart enough to realise that `F: Debug` ⇒ `MyError<F>: Debug`, or there's a problem with assuming so.

Comment: The constraint on the `impl` is actually `F::Err: Debug`, since the enum variant `Parse` contains an `F::Err`, not an `F`. (Though `rustc --pretty=expanded` *also* puts an `F: Debug` constraint on the `impl`, but I can't see why.)